# how to fix scroll bug in tmux?

Tags: linux, cygwin, tmux

I know it's sound scary but it's probably not related only to cygwin.
As you know cygwin uses xterm, and i ssh'ed to another machine where I've launched tmux.
On one machine I've got mouse enabled for tmux and it works almost fine when scrolling.
While scrolling a screen with mouse, I've got some random characters appearing in command line, but at least scrolling works, but I've got machine where I can't have my own configuration, so scrolling with keyboard is really buggy. After I go to scroll mode with this shortcut `ctrl+b [`, I can scroll only through visible area, then everything random characters appears in command line, and it's just doesn't allow me to scroll up at all. and what's the most interesting thing that with enabled mouse, using scrolling with keyboard is fine, well i still got this random chars appearing but it's fine as long as scrolling works.

So my question is how to get rid of random characters which are appearing while scrolling with mouse/keyboard?

my tmux.config where mouse is enabled:

```
set-option -g mode-mouse on
set-option -g mouse-select-pane on
set-option -g mouse-select-window on
```

Comment: if anybody thinks my questions is wrong please edit my post.

Comment: You may want to search for or mention this on the tmux-users mailing list; this sounds similar to a problem I had with `tmux` using a different terminal emulator (iTerm2 on Mac OS X). (I never got a fix; I just turned off the mouse settings.)

Comment: well as I stated without mouse scrolling doesn't work at all

Comment: Ive got this too on linux, but only sometimes.. Perhaps it is vi keys.. many of them are like `:a` etc..

Comment: Try tmux set mouse-utf8 off as some terminals might not support mouse-utf8.Terminals need to support "utf8 mouse", and if they don't this are the symptoms experienced. Switching to putty or uxterm might solve the issue.

Comment: tmux is used as a tool primarily for programming. imho

Comment: For me this happens only, when i connect to a remote via ssh and then the connection gets closed by remote (reboot / timeout). If i end the connection with 'exit', i got no problems.